# Align icon to text size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display an image in an icon next to a piece of text. It sits slightly below the text and I'd like it to at least be the same height as the text aka vertically aligned to the middle.

```css
.text {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    color: black;
}

.em-image{
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/r8hkG1o.png);
}

[class^="em-"], [class*=" em-"], .em-png {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p class="text"><i class="em-image"></i> Name</p>
```

It's currently looking like this
[image: Example of current output]
Whereas I'd prefer it to look like this
[image: Example of desired output]

Is there a way to at least make the image match the line height? The image sits at the bottom now but I'd like it the full height and aligned vertically to the text, I'm just not sure how to go about this, could the same be done with a span or a DIV containing the image as a background instead?

Comment: `vertical-align: text-top` comes darn close for me

Comment: That doesn't make it the same height as the text unfortunately @j08691

Answer (score 3):

I Suggest that use  vertical-align:baseline and use 'rem' instead 'em' that should work.

```css
.text {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    color: black;
}

.em-image{
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/r8hkG1o.png);
}

[class^="em-"], [class*=" em-"], .em-png {
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<p class="text"><i class="em-image"></i> Name</p>
```

Comment: I needed to an icon to line up relatively to an API error message response. I had specific styles  for each element (i.e. error icon and error content) I just had a wrapper and played the following
display: flex;
align-items: center

This helped my icon alignment woes.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Flexbox and `<span>` instead of `<p>` to achieve this. With the Flexbox approach you can center all the items horizontally and vertically.

Why `<span>`? Because it is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 1;
}

span {
  margin: 0 0 0 .25em;
}

.em-image {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/r8hkG1o.png);
  height: 1em; /* Change this value to match the desired height */
  width: 1em; /* Change this value to match the desired width */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <i class="em-image"></i>
  <span>Name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Try to find the height of the text and make max height to the icon equal to the height of the text

you may try to add this CSS code:

```
[class^="em-"], [class*=" em-"], .em-png {
                                             max-height: 200px;
}
```

if the icon is larger smaller than the text height try to increase or decrease the icon height

i hop this answer helps

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use `inline-flex` to the class **.text** (instead of inline-block)

then you can just give the icon a `align-self: center` and it should be what you are looking for. You will probably need to adjust the spacing but should be good.

```
.text {
  display: inline-flex;
}

[class^="em-"] {
  align-self: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest several things:

- **Use "em"**, as you were doing. "rem" will take the root font-size, and will break the component if that changes, while "em" will keep the image size proportional to the label text.
- **Use flexbox**. It's shorter, more clear and modern.
- [No font actually occupies the whole vertical space](https://material.io/design/typography/understanding-typography.html#type-properties). There is some extra space above and bellow. The typography you are using, Roboto, occupies **approximately 80% of the vertical space**, so that should be reflected in your css if want to be really precise.
- Optional: the font is also not exactly centered, it has **slightly more space bellow than above**, so you'll need to correct this, by a factor of 2%.

The final code would be:

```css
.text {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.em-image{
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/r8hkG1o.png);
}

[class^="em-"], [class*=" em-"], .em-png {
    height: .8em;
    width: .8em;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-right: .25em;
    margin-top: -.02em;
}
```

```html
<p class="text"><i class="em-image"></i> Name</p>
```